# How to make phantomjs remember a login session?

Tags: javascript, session, phantomjs, captcha

I am using PhantomJS to test a website. However, when you login to this website, you have to enter a CAPTCHA string. I try to render the page, then enter the CAPTCHA from console and pass it to the CAPTCHA field, but the page reloads again and my string does not match the CAPTCHA anymore. I guess it's a session problem.

So I want to know if there is any way that I can login to this page on a browser (Firefox or Chrome...) and do something so that when my PhantomJS program opens that page, it will lead to the main page, not the login page. Or is there any better solution?